# CKEditor data does not upload in firestore with TypeError: text is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ckeditor

I keep on having this error with these codes:

> TypeError: text is not a function

```
const [text, setText] = useState("");
```

handlesubmit:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const userRef = firestore.collection("announcement").doc();
      const ref = userRef.set({
        text,
      });
      text("");
      console.log(" saved");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

inside the return of the functional component:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <CKEditor
              editor={ClassicEditor}
              data={text}
              onChange={(event, editor1) => {
                const data = editor1.getData();
                setText(data);
              }}
            />
            <br />
            <br />
            <ButtonForm type="submit">Submit</ButtonForm>
          </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setText("")` instead `text("");` on `handleSubmit`